# Access to property defined in child class from static method in the parent class - javascript

Tags: javascript, class

Is there a way to have a parent class with static methods that call a property defined in the child class in javascript? The code idea would be something like this:

```
class Base {
    static greet() {
        return `Hi ${username}!`
    }
} 

class ChildClass extends Base {
    username = "Jim"
} 

ChildClass.greet()
```

Comment: This makes no sense atm. `name = "Jim"` will create  property on an *instance*. Static methods operate on the class itself though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access properties of the class (also inherited ones) via `this`, and you can set properties of the subclass just the way you do with every other object:

```
 class Base {
   static greet() {
      return `Hi ${this.otherName}!`; // << you need this. here
   }
 } 

 class Child extends Base {  } 

  Child.otherName = "Jim"; // << there are no static properties yet, we have to replicate that behaviour
```

---

<sub>`name` is a bad property name, as it clashes with the internal `function.name` ...</sub>

Comment: Using this code, console.log(Child.greet()) prints "Hi Child!" https://codepen.io/NiuZh/pen/NWWQoYZ?editors=0011

Comment: I got it to work configuring the name property Object.defineProperty(Child, 'name', { writable: true, value: 'Jim' })

Comment: @David: You should probably choose a different name for the property. `name` is a default property of functions (and `Child` is a function).

Comment: Oh, that's indeed a bad property name, as it clashes with `function.name` ...